# SSH into remote host from Jenkins docker container

Tags: docker

I am running docker container and as part of one job I have to ssh into remote host and execute few commands in the remote host.
I am following the below approach .

1. Started Jenkins container and it's running fine
2. Checked whether I am able to ping remote instance and it's working fine. Also I am able to ssh with password.
3. Now I have generated public and private key in docker container and push the public key in the authorized_keys of remote host.
4. When I am tried to do passwordless SSH it's going to password method.

Below is the output from debug mode -

```
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa (0x56281fc480e0)
debug2: key: /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Not sure what I am missing as I am following exact same approach while doing passwordless SSH from docker host to remote machine and it's working fine.

Any help appreciated , thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure the server supports RSA keys?

Comment: please let me know if you are you talking about Docker host or remote server , FYI I am able to do passwordless ssh between Docker host and remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue .
Enable logging for sshd and in /var/log/messages found the error that bad permission on the home folder.

Below two links helped to resolve -

https://www.howtogeek.com/168156/fixing-authentication-refused-bad-ownership-or-modes-for-directory/

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152594/understanding-the-offering-rsa-public-key-step-during-ssh-connection-initializ